# Reading a txt file and finding the average of the numbers in python

Tags: python

My task is to read a txt file that i already written, display the numbers separately on each line, and get the average of the numbers using a **loop**.  This is what I have so far.

```
data = []
def main():
    f = open('tests.txt', 'r')
    for line in tests:
        amout = float(line)
        print(format(amount, '.3f'))
        print avg()
        tests.close()
def avg():
    for line in f:
        fields = line.split()
        rowdata = map(float, fields)
        data.extend(rowdata)
        average = (sum(data)/len(data))
        print("The average is", average)
main()
```

Comment: Do you have any question for us?

Comment: What am I doing wrong? Been stuck on this for while.

Comment: if you read what error says, you see that you made a typo: `amout = float(line)`

Comment: You should separate your concerns. Write a method that gets a pure numerical data structure from your file. You can then write a method that only focuses on getting the average or whatever you want. Less confusion this way.

Comment: I didn't see that, whoops.  It still says invalid syntax and highlights avg().

Comment: @Redblaster13 Are you using python3?

Comment: and where is the loop you are supposed to use? This is curious, that you know what `map()` is and you don't know how to do such simple task...

Comment: yes I'm using python 3.  I googled allot of information, after i couldn't figure this out.

Comment: `print` was changed to a function instead of a statement, so you have to use `print(...)` instead of `print ...`.

Comment: what are `tests`? shouldn't it be `for line in tests:`? Please, do your basic debugging on your own, and if you really get stuck, post good question, with exact error you get.

Comment: Sorry for taking up your time I'm just new to python and just needed some help.

Comment: @Redblaster13 No worries. What I think you should do is install Python 2 since most tutorials assume that's what you're using. You should then go through an end to end tutorial at a slow pace instead of banging your head on problems like this and just not enjoying yourself at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  It runs on 2.5 through 3.4.

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.4/bin/python

'''Compute average of numbers in tests.txt'''

# pylint: disable=superfluous-parens
# superfluous-parens: Parentheses are good for clarity and portability

from __future__ import with_statement


def main():
    '''Main function'''
    numbers = []
    with open('tests.txt', 'r') as file_:
        for line in file_:
            fields = line.split()
            print(line.rstrip('\n'))
            subnumbers = (float(field) for field in fields)
            numbers.extend(subnumbers)
    print('The average is %s' % avg(numbers))


def avg(numbers):
    '''Compute average'''
    average = (sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
    return average

main()
```

Or as part of a larger program, see http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/stddev.html

Thanks.